# Display data in JTable with selection of check boxes in Swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, checkbox

```
    String callType = " ";

    if (local_checkbox.isSelected()) {
        callType = callType + "and toc ='Local'";
    }

    if (std_checkbox.isSelected()) {
        callType = callType + "and toc ='STD'";
    }
    if (isd_checkbox.isSelected()) {
        callType = callType + "and toc ='ISD'";
    }
    if (incoming_checkbox.isSelected()) {
        callType = callType + "and toc ='INCOMING'";

    }
    if (transfered_checkbox.isSelected()) {
        callType = callType + "and toc ='Transfered'";

    }
    if (conference_checkbox.isSelected()) {
        callType = callType + "and toc ='Conference'";
    }
    if (missed_checkbox.isSelected()) {
        callType = callType + "and toc ='Missed'";
    }

    int i = 4;
    callType = callType.substring(i);
    callType = callType.replace("and", "or");
    callType = "and\t" + callType;
    i++;

 try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        checkUserInputs chkusrin = new checkUserInputs();
        query = chkusrin.formatQuery(reportType, resultDateFrom, resultDateTo, empid, trunk, dialedno, duration, site, authcode, extension, cost, department, callType, time);
        System.out.println(query);
        ps = con1.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        table1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
 }catch(Exception e) {}
    `
```

I have multiple Check Boxes. They are Type of calls, the check boxes are `STD`, `ISD`, `Missed` etc.. In the database I have a column named "Type of Calls" which have the values `STD`, `ISD`, `missed` etc... The task given to me  is as follows :

1. To Display data in the `JTable` based on the Selection of the check boxes. So , if a user selects the check box `STD`, the table would show me only STD calls with the other details, and if a user selects the check box `ISD` , the table would show me only `ISD` Calls with other details and so on. I'm able to do this.
2. Problem is When a user selects multiple check boxes. Say I select `ISD` and `STD`, then my table has to show all the `STD` and `ISD` calls with their Values.

The function formatQuery has all the queries and the conditions to fetch the data from the database.

How do I implement this?

Comment: Do the different types use different columns? If so, you'll need multiple JTables, one for each type. (Unless I'm misunderstanding your issue...)

Comment: I'd say load all the data at start-up but implement a [`TableRowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) to filter them as needed.

Comment: @Manu No they do not use different types. Everything is just in one column which is Type of Call.

Comment: Hey Andrew , I already have implemented a table row sorter. But , i need to Display the Type of call based on the user Selection.

Comment: You have a very random way of using upper case letters which makes the words hard for me to read.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.  Otherwise, use lower case.  And a tip: Add @Manu (or whoever, **the `@` is important**) to **notify** the person of a new comment.

Comment: @Rajeev Please attach the code you currently use to fill your JTable, based on the checkboxes.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I do apologize for the usage of upper case letters. I'll make sure i don't do that again . Thanks for the tip .

Comment: @Manu kindly check the code that I have tried and please let me know if I need to change anything .